# NPM install problem cannot download win32-x64-83_binding.node

Tags: node.js, sass, npm-install

When trying to install npm I get the error that win32-x64-83_binding.node cannot be downloaded:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.

> fsevents@1.2.13 install C:\Users\***\node_modules\fsevents
> node install.js


Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform win32 is not supported

> node-sass@4.13.1 install C:\Users\***\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/win32-x64-83_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/win32-x64-83_binding.node":

HTTP error 404 Not Found

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080
```

If I go to the link: https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.13.1/win32-x64-83_binding.node I get a 404 page not found error.

What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please provide node,js version you are working with?

Comment: version of Node: v14.15.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are facing issue due to the version incompatibility.

The version you are trying to install is 4.13.1 of node-saas, while this version is not supported by Node 14+.

You can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass#node-version-support-policy)

With Node 14+, you need to install 4.14+ version of node-saas.

Comment: so, instead of running `npm install node-sass` I should be running what comand? (note: I'm a complete novice to node.js/npm)

Comment: Try npm install node-sass@4.14.1

Comment: I changed the version to 4.14.1 in package.json and ran `npm install node-sass` and it now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove node-sass folder from node-modules.

**run**

```
npm install node-sass@4.14.1
```

This will create required node-sass binary file *win32-x64-83_binding.node* which is required to compile sass files which is compatible with node version 14+.

Click [here](https://github.com/sass/node-sass) for checking compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download/save the appropriate node-sass version from Github
2. set the environment variable
   export SASS_BINARY_PATH=C:/Users/my_username/Downloads/win32-x64-83_binding.node
3. Run npm cache verify
4. Run npm install

Comment: That file doesn't actually exist in GitHub.